# How to automatically right click on jtable and select first JMenu item

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpopupmenu

I have a swing application where we pass a json to the textfield and after clicking on load button, a table is getting populated.

I am able to load the json and selected the whole table automatically through following code:

```
  resourceButton.doClick();
  this.table.selectAll();
```

Now I want to right click on the selected table and choose first option from the popupmenu. Any suggestions?

I want to automate this particular part of UI:

```
    JMenuItem addToSiteMap = new JMenuItem("Add to site map");
    addToSiteMap
        .addActionListener(e -> IntStream.of(tab.getTable().getSelectedRows()).forEach(row -> {
          int index = (int) tab.getTable()
              .getValueAt(row, tab.getTable().getColumn("#").getModelIndex());
          HttpRequestResponse httpRequestResponse = this.httpRequestResponses.get(index);
          callbacks.addToSiteMap(httpRequestResponse);
        }));
```

Comment: The purpose of using a popup is to allow the user to choose an Action from the popup. If you always want to invoke the first item in the popup then how does the user invoke the 2nd or 3rd item? If you only have one item then you should NOT use a popup because the user doesn't expect something to happen automatically. Instead you should add a button to frame so when the user clicks the button the Action will be performed on all selected items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use button for this purpose instead of the popup menu. You can add the button and write an action listener on it like below

```
button.addActionListener(e -> IntStream.of(this.getTable().getSelectedRows()).forEach(row -> {
      int index = (int) this.getTable()
              .getValueAt(row, this.getTable().getColumn("#").getModelIndex());
      HttpRequestResponse httpRequestResponse = this.httpRequestResponses.get(index);
      resourceTextField.setText(String.valueOf(index));
  callbacks.addToSiteMap(httpRequestResponse);
    }));
```

Comment: Yep, that is what I suggested a couple of hours ago. I guess I could have posted an answer, but I assume if the OP knows how to add an ActionListener to a JMenuItem, then know how to add an ActionListener to a JButton.

Comment: I am automating the stuff, so I dont have option to change the UI. Though what you are saying is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to right click on the selected table and choose first option from the popupmenu.

A popup menu contains `JMenuItem`s or `JMenu`s. Either way, the ones with an actual action are the `JMenuItem`s.

A `JMenuItem` is a button as well. You already use `resourceButton.doClick()`. You can use `doClick` to a `JMenuItem` too.

An example:

```
public class TableTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][] { { "something" } }, new String[] { "column" });

            JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("MenuItem");
            menuItem.addActionListener(e -> {
                System.out.println("Popup item clicked.");
            });
            popupMenu.add(menuItem);

            table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);

            frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JButton button = new JButton("Click me to fire Popupmenu item");
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                menuItem.doClick();
            });
            frame.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: will it trigger a right click. because doclick() will do a left click

Comment: Hi I have edited my question.Can u look into it if that would help you

Comment: @YatinKanyal Why don't simply call `addToSiteMap.doClick()`?

Comment: I tried this but nothing happened. Am I missing something.  Does this code has to do anything?        HttpRequestResponse httpRequestResponse = this.httpRequestResponses.get(index);
          callbacks.addToSiteMap(httpRequestResponse);

Comment: @YatinKanyal If it is a heavy operation - takes time, yes it plays role.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218983/discussion-between-yatin-kanyal-and-george-z).